# How do I bind a Boolean property to BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I simply have custom UIView called CheckboxView with property `isSelected: Bool`. How do I observe that value and bind it to another property in my view model?

```
let isSelected = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)

class CheckboxView: UIView {
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}


let view = CheckboxView()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it? I suspect there is a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Is your goal here to have the `isSelected` relay to emit a value every time `view.isSelected` changes value, or the other way around?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to have isSelected relay value up to date when isSelected from checkboxView changes

Comment: And additionally every time when it changes I need to call sth else like updateView().

Comment: Something in your checkbox view is able to register when the user taps the screen, either a button or a gesture recognizer. That thing has an Observable associated with it, and that is where the chain should start. Show that code.

Comment: checkboxview is just a view with Uiimageview

Comment: What side effect(s) triggers the `isSelected` boolean to change?